# How to scroll to top after login?

Tags: ios, objective-c, scroll

I have a click button sender code as below to redirect back to tabbarcontroller (index 0). But how can I set to scroll to top (setContentOffset:CGPointZero)? Please help.

```
-(void) clickLogin:(UIButton*)sender
{
    //Back to Home page
    int index = 0;
    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = index;
    [self.tabBarController.viewControllers[index] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];

}
```

Comment: you want your user just back to top page by clicking on the button that it ?

Comment: Hi J.Doe, I click this button from Viewcontroller B and expected result is redirect back to viewcontroller A and scroll to top.

Comment: What the content of A tableView Or scrollView ??

Comment: HI Sh_khan, Scrollview

Comment: Ho you are in objective-C I have never wrote one line of it ^^, but maybe I can give you some hint. Basically you got to put a _callback_ onClick the send button which put forward the Viewcontroller A, also take the coordinate of topPage Element and set it to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `viewDidAppear` of VC A , can you try

```
self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0,0); // OR CGPointZero
```